# How to check last array object

Tags: jquery

I have an array object:

```
var checkin_status = [
{"startdate":"2015-01-08",
"totaldays":"3",
"roadmap":[
        {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":100,"day":1},
        {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":500,"day":3},
        {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1000,"day":10},
        {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1200,"day":20}
      ]

}];
```

I use `$.each` to display them to view, now how can I check last object in `roadmap` ? Because I have to give some condition for the last object. Any suggestion to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @tabz100 Uncaught ReferenceError: roadmap is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//assuming that you already have a better logic to select the roadmap from the checkin_status object
//assign the current roadmap object to a local var before you iterate through it
var roadmap = checkin_status[0].roadmap;
$.each(roadmap, function (index, item) {
   //'item' is the object of the current iteration..
   if (index === roadmap.length - 1) {
      //do something special with the last item
   }
});
```

The reason for `length - 1` is because, arrays are indexed by 0 in Javascript. For ex., if you have 4 items, then the last item is index 3.